# PowerShell AzureRM commands -- avoiding expiry in Save-AzureRMProfile

Tags: powershell, azure

I have automated an Azure deployment using `AzureRM` commandlets. Those commandlets need a login, so I tried to provide a saved profile using `Save-AzureRMProfile`/`Select-AzureRMProfile`.

However after some time profile seems to expire and I need to login again. I want to run my script automatically on a schedule, so manual re-login is not a solution.

How can I avoid the profile expiry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't avoid the expiry, your token expires and needs to be reauthenticated. (it would be worrying if those credentials could be persisted) - However

`Add-AzureRmAccount` does take a pscredential parameter. So you can save your credentials to a file and instead automatically log in with live credentials every time.

You can just use the standard pscredential save mechanisms, the problem in this for you is that a pscredential isn't transportable, to get around this you can create your own key to pass to pscredential.

```
$key = New-Object byte[](32)
$rng = [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create()
$rng.GetBytes($key)
```

You can then use this key to create a transportable secure string. Obviously this key is your authentication at this point, so it needs to be stored securely.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$SecureStringWithKey = $cred.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $key
```

You can encode the key with base64 and add it as an environment variable etc

```
$base64key = [Convert]::ToBase64String($key)
```

At the other end, decode the string

```
$key  = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64key)
```

and push it back through SecureString,  and rebuild a credential object.

```
$secureStringPassword = $AuthObject.SecureStringWithKey | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key 
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
             -argumentlist $Username, $secureStringPassword
```

You can then log in with

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
```

My personal approach to all of this was to create a psobject with all of those details saved, (they key, the tenantid, and the pscredential) to create a json string, and then encrypt that with a certificate. That way I can store the encrypted json file on a blob, and download, decrypt and sign in on any system I'm sat at.

Comment: Thanks! Some notes in case people have a similar issue: 1. Login using -Credential for some reason never reports a failure unless you request a specific TenantId (and maybe SubscriptionId?). It returns successfully, but other commands don't work. 2. This does not work with a Microsoft account, but you can always create a user in Azure AD (only found that on the old portal) and use that.