# How do I publish Azure Management Powershell Scripts to an Azure Machine and have them run

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, azure

I have an ASP.NET app that I have been running locally during testing and everything's been working fine, but now I've gotten to a point that I need to publish my app to an Azure VM and it needs to continue managing the cloud, from the cloud.

I will need to modify my powershell scripts in such a way that credentials are obtainable from my Azure Account somehow instead of being manually entered (a la Login-AzureAccount) so that the scripts can still be run successfully - at least partially because I don't want to store my personal credentials in the app, not that I could if I wanted to as it's protected with 2 factor authentication).

A ton of the information I have found appears to be out of date. What is the most current correct way of obtaining and storing credentials that will work both locally and from within the context of an Azure VM?

Comment: Well... the Azure Subscription is presently logged in under an account that has 2 factor auth - which must be done manually, I need to switch the app to use a certificate, but I have no idea how to get my app to set this up and provide the resulting certificate to powershell to use instead of the creds provided by Login-AzureAccount

Comment: Are you using Azure RM cmdlets or Azure (classic - SM) cmdlets? - can you create an Azure Service Principal?

Comment: @MichaelB I'm using AzureRM

Comment: My answer would be largely based on a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960691/powershell-azurerm-commands-avoiding-expiry-in-save-azurermprofile/34961029#34961029) I've written, does that sound like what you're looking for? (particularly the bit at the botttom)

Comment: Well... the account I have been using is an MS account protected with 2FA, your notes suggest it wouldn't work. I don't have access to the AD in this subscription... I have access to the management certificates. I wonder if this could be adapted?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work, you can't run Azure RM commands through a management certificate credential. You'd either need a AAD account or a Service Principal to authorize against. And you can't log in with an MS account because it needs to be interactive (even without 2FA)

Comment: Do you have any pointers toward setting that up securely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101721/discussion-between-michael-b-and-benalabaster).