# Azure Powershell - automating Login-AzureRmAccount AD Login - for Azure function

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I have [this Azure Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627558/export-sql-azure-db-to-blob-start-azuresqldatabaseexport-cannot-convert-azur/43649820#43649820), which successfully backs up a SQL Azure DB to Azure Blob.

In its current form, it requires me to log in via AD.

I now need to implement this script to execute via a Azure Function at specific intervals.

The first snippet of the script:

```
$subscriptionId = "YOUR AZURE SUBSCRIPTION ID"

Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
```

I thus need to not use Login-AzureRmAccount, but replace it with a method that does not require human input.

I have found this link:

https://cmatskas.com/automate-login-for-azure-powershell-scripts/

- In short, the author:

  1. Creates an Azure AD Application (with its own password)
  2. Creates a Service Principal
  3. Assigns Permissions to the Service Principal

This is a once-off manual creation - which is perfect.

The author then logs in to this newly created application

```
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)


Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId e801a3ad-3690-4aa0-a142-1d77cb360b07 -ServicePrincipal
```

My questions:

1. Is this what I should do to be able to automate my application and prevent human login?
2. This Azure AD app created in step 1 - can I use this app as a starting point in my of my Azure functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use that route, or use certificate auth, or use an Azure AD user, it can login with user\password, but is considered less secure than service principal.
2. Yes, you can use one service principal for any number of Azure Functions you would like to.

Comment: Thanks 4c74356b41 - when you say use an Azure AD user - does it refer to saving the AD Users username and password in the powershell script which would then make it less secure?

Comment: well, you have to save service principal credentials also, so that's not the case

Comment: SP is slightly better in that you can easily revoke if compromised (no use is inconvenienced) and you can restrict perms to only those are necessary.  Technically possible but more inconvenient if you use an orgId...

Answer (score 1):

To use Azure PowerShell in Azure Functions, you may refer to the following response in another SO thread.  The example is an HTTP-Trigger, but you can modify it to use a Timer-Trigger for your use-case.  Here's the link:

[Azure Function role like permissions to Stop Azure Virtual Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838619/azure-function-role-like-permissions-to-stop-azure-virtual-machines/40883318#40883318)

Answer (score 0):

Run PowerShell as Administrator, you need to install AzureRM in PowerShell,

- Login to Azure

`Login-AzureRmAccount`

- Enter your Azure credentials
- To get your subscription(s) details
  enter

`Get-AzureRmSubscription`

- Use the subscription id to select the subscription.

`Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

- Save the AzureProfile using the below command

`Save-AzureRmProfile -Path "C:\AzureScripts\profile.json"`

- The json file can be used to login to Azure

`Select-AzureRmProfile -Path "C:\AzureScripts\profile.json"`

Put this line on top of you .ps1 file, ***you does not require human input***.

Ref : http://www.smartcoding.in/blog/auto-login-azure-power-shell

Comment: token expires, your script turns into a pumpkin, don't up vote this answer.

Comment: This script works for me..  http://www.smartcoding.in/blog/start-stop-azure-vm-with-power-shell/

Comment: Am using this for start stop vm .. are you using Azure Resource Manager?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960691/powershell-azurerm-commands-avoiding-expiry-in-save-azurermprofile